# Can a Composite video to VGA adapter be used both ways?

Tags: vga, adapter, composite-video

[image]

I would like to use this adapter to display the video signal from my Wii console on my LCD monitor.

Now, I found such an adapter in my local classifieds, however those products are advertised to deliver the video signal from a PC graphics card VGA port to the Composite video cable connector (and than to a TV for instance).

So the video signal inside the adapter goes from the VGA connector to the Composite video connector.

As I mentioned above, I need it to go in the other direction - from the Composite video connector to the VGA connector.

Would this work?
Can the adapter pictured above be used "both ways"?

I'm not expert but my logic tells me that the adapter is a primitive component so it "shouldn't care" in which way the video signal goes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In all likelyhood, that adapter will not work at all in your situation.  VGA-to-video cables ("video" meaning composite, S-video or component) will only work with graphic adapters that specifically output those extra video signals on unused pins of the HD15 connector.  Since most graphic adapters do not output any video signals other than the RGBHV (red, green, blue, horizontal sync and vertical sync) for VGA, there will be no output when you use such a cable.  It is simply impossible to create luminance and chrominance NTSC signals for composite video and S-video from RGBHV using a passive LCR circuit.

Conversely, the VGA inputs of monitors do not typically do double duty and allow video signals other than RGBHV to be input through the HD15 connector.  It the monitor accepts a composite video signal, then there should be a RCA (or BNC) connector.

Comment: I understand. I solved the issue by buying a video capture card with a composite-in port. The visual quality on my 24" LCD is not as good as on my CRT TV, but it's playable `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the plugs are the right type then you should be OK with this.

I'm sure you are correct in assuming that the device won't care which way the signal travels.

Comment: I hope so `:)` I'll try that out...